# Fetching date,month and year form nested model in sequalize PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, group-by, model, nested, sequelize.js

How to fetch month, and year separately form nested included model?

I have 2 models, user and category

> The User model has `userName`, `phone`, `category_id` and `status`.
>
> The category model has `catName`, `description`

I would like to categorize the number of users registered under a particular category according to month and year wise.

Expected Output:

```
"catName": "sports",
        "stat": [
            {
                    "month": 2,
                    "year": 2018
                "count": 2
            },
            {
                    "month": 3,
                    "year": 2018
                "count": 2
            },...}]
```

I have tried this

```
const test = await models.Category.findAll({
    attributes: { 
        include: [
        [models.sequelize.fn("COUNT", models.sequelize.col("User.id")), "Count"]] 
    },
   
    include: [{
        model: models.User, as:'User', attributes: 
        [[models.sequelize.fn('date_trunc', 'Month' 'Year', models.sequelize.col('created_at')), 'Month','Year'],]
    }],
    group: ['Category.id','Month','year']
})
```

Comment: _I have tried this_.. and what was the result?

Comment: @Ankh getting this error `SequelizeDatabaseError: column reference "created_at" is ambiguous`

Comment: So I assume both categories and users have the field `created_at`? You'll need to specify which one you're referencing e.g. `User.created_at`